# Two particles of different velocities travel through a region of time-dependant acceleration. At what time do they meet afterwards?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics

Two projectiles: $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ have velocities $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$, both propagting in the x direction and starting at $x=0$. They propagate with constant velocity over a distance $L$ and reach a region of time dependant acceleration $L<x<L+\Delta L$. $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ are accelerated by $a_{1}(t)$ and $a_{2}(t)$ respectively, over the region of length $\Delta L$. After exiting the accelerating region (i.e. $x>L+\Delta L$) they travel at a constant velocity. At what $x$ value do $P_1$ and $P_2$ meet? Also how would you treat this problem if the particles were moving with relativistic speeds?

The thing that confuses me is the integral over $a_t$ that's present in both the velocity as a function of time and the position as a function of time for the acceleration region:
(Calling the time of arrival at the accelerating region $t_i$ and the time exiting $t_f$)

$$x_{accel}(t) = L + \int_{t_{i}}^{t_{f}}[v(t_i) + \int_{t_i}^{t_f} a(t) dt]dt $$

Both have limits containing the time of exiting the region ($t_f$). I would think to use the $x_{accel}(t_f) = L + \Delta L$ and solve for this time, but as it contains this term itself I'm not sure.